# Stop axios request call in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to stop axios request.
I use `useInterval(custom hooks)`(I referenced a website) to request api.

So I stop it with `useState` and it's totally stopped when i set interval like 1000ms.
however, when i set interval like 100ms then i can't stop api request. it's stopped after 3seconds or something.

So i tried to use `if` statement. but it's not working as i expected.

and I also checked Network from development tool on chrome

and the request Status was getting changed from pending to 200

and when all the request's Status change to 200, then it stopped.

I really want to know how i can stop API request properly.

my code is like this

## useInterval

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";

const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  const savedCallback = useRef(callback);

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const tick = () => {
      savedCallback.current();
    };

    if (delay !== null) {
      const id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
};

export default useInterval;
```

## API calling

```js
  const [API_DATA, setAPI_DATA] = useState(null);
  const [apiStart, setApiStart] = useState(false);
  const [spinner, setSpinner] = useState(false);
  //Request API 
  const getAPI = useCallback(async () => {
    if (apiStart) {
      await axios
        .get(API_URL, {
          headers: Header,
        })
        .then(response => {
          setAPI_DATA(response.data);
          setSpinner(false);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          init();
          console.log("error");
        });
    }
  }, [API_DATA,  spinner]);
  
  // start API 
    const start_API = () => {
    setSpinner(true);
    setApiStart(true);
  };
  
 //stop API 
   const stop_API = () => {
    setSpinner(false);
    alert("API STOP");
    setApiStart(false);
  };
  
 //using useInterval
    useInterval(
    () => {
      if (apiStart) return getAPI();
    },
    apiStart ? 100 : null
  );
```

Comment: You can't stop the request after it has been triggered but you could ignore the response. Have a look at https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go take a look at the axios documentation at https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation. I would remove the `if(apiStart)` as this does not do much. I would possibly rewrite your this method as follows:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
const [spinnerActive, setSpinnerActive] = useState(false);

const controller = new AbortController();
const getAPI = useCallback(async () => {
    setSpinnerActive(true);
    await axios
        .get(API_URL, {
            headers: Header,
            signal: controller.signal
        })
        .then(response => {
            setData(response.data);
            setSpinnerActive(false);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            setSpinnerActive(false);
            console.log("error");
        });

}, [data, spinnerActive]);

useInterval(
    () => {
        getApi()
    },
    apiStart ? 100 : null
);
```

Then when you want to abort the request, call `controller.abort()`